# CBIND function and adding correct colname

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

I have a dataframe with the following structure.

```
     FECHA              FECHA_EXCEL
1 2015-05-25 12:00:00       42149
2 2015-05-26 12:00:00       42150
3 2015-05-27 12:00:00       42151
4 2015-05-28 12:00:00       42152
5 2015-05-29 12:00:00       42153
6 2015-06-01 12:00:00       42156
```

I want to add to this dataframe columns that are generated from my code.

I have like 45 products and I want to add 45 new columns to my dataframe and in its column name I want the name of each product.

For example for my product 1 I have a Dataframe with the following structure.

```
FECHA                 FECHA_EXCEL sd  mean   Rto_diario Rto_ventana senial_sigma Volatility_rol precio_M_Mean_menos3Sigma
1 2015-05-25 12:00:00       42149 NA   NA           NA          NA           NA             NA                        NA
2 2015-05-26 12:00:00       42150 NA   NA -0.007242345          NA           NA             NA                        NA
3 2015-05-27 12:00:00       42151 NA   NA  0.016974636          NA           NA             NA                        NA
4 2015-05-28 12:00:00       42152 NA   NA -0.004225315          NA           NA             NA                        NA
5 2015-05-29 12:00:00       42153 NA   NA -0.014513125          NA           NA             NA                        NA
6 2015-06-01 12:00:00       42156 NA   NA  0.001827485          NA           NA             NA
```

I want to add to my new dataframe my column named as "Volatilily_Rol" and its column name should be the name of this product, the product name is saved in a variable called, "product_name".

Here is my code for creating this new dataframe.

dfRolVoling (it is my new DF)
dfsigma_ (old DF where I obtain the column I want to add)

```
cbind(dfRolVoling, product_name=dfsigma_$Volatility_rol)
```

But in my new DF isn't not appearing its name correctly, do you know any function where I can add a new COL to my dataframe with a concrete name?

It's my new DF using this function.

```
     FECHA               FECHA_EXCEL    product_name
1 2015-05-25 12:00:00       42149             NA
2 2015-05-26 12:00:00       42150             NA
3 2015-05-27 12:00:00       42151             NA
4 2015-05-28 12:00:00       42152             NA
5 2015-05-29 12:00:00       42153             NA
6 2015-06-01 12:00:00       42156             NA
```

Product_name colname should be it's correct name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have this result you can simply add the column by using `df$colname <- NA` This will setup your new column. In your case it should be `dfRolVoling$product_name <- NA`. That should do the trick.